# I want to put content in a container that takes the height of the screen

Tags: html, css

I want to make a container in the middle of the screen and put some div itmes in.
I want sth like this.
I stripped down the html to its essentials for you people.

```
   <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="nl">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<title>Webshop</title>
<link href="../css/boilerplate.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<style type="text/css">
#content {
    position:relative;
    width:200px;
    height:115px;
    background-color:#F00;
    top: 900px;
    margin:10px;
    padding:10px;
    display:inline-block;
}
#container {
    max-width: 960px;
    background: #FFF;
    margin: 0 auto;
    min-height:100%;
    height: auto;
    padding-top:0;
    padding-left:1em;
    padding-right:1em;
    padding-bottom:0;

}
</style>

</head>
<body style="background-color:#CF6" >
<div id="container">
  <div id="content"> </div> 
  <div id="content"> </div> 
  <div id="content"> </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The result is awful.

Comment: you can google absolute centering

Comment: *The result is awful.* - this is a subjective statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont really understand, what you want but have a look at this :

http://jsfiddle.net/u7k6cyf5/

```
#content {
position:relative;
width:200px;
background-color:#F00;
margin:10px;
padding:10px;
display:inline-block;
```

}

Comment: Thanks a lot man, this really helped! Is there a way to extend the container all the way down to the bottom of the page, regardless of the content?

Comment: I did nothing than just removing your top and height from "content". Anyhow, if your have the result that you expected, that's great. Mark the answer accepted and carry on ;) Thank you.